# Is MarioKartOutfit "C" real?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

I have went to many websites looking for an answer and I got many responses. For example, the Wikipedia said that there is a way to unlock mii outfit C while most of the other websites concluded that it was either a glitch or not real at all. Does anyone know if mii outfit C is real? If it is, I'd appreciate if you could tell me how to unlock it. Thank you for reading!

Comment: don't trust wikis, they are often edited by people who don't know

Answer (score 5):

In short, no. Multitudes of people have modded their ISOs for use when running an emulator such as [Dolphin](https://dolphin-emu.org) to create a custom racer or to change the appearance of one of the already existing racers.

From [Super Mario Wiki](http://www.mariowiki.com/)'s [Mii](http://www.mariowiki.com/Mii) page:

> Originally, a Mii Outfit C was going to be added, but was cut from the
>   final version of the game.

Comment: For the record, the cut outfit does still exist in the game files: http://tcrf.net/File:MKWii_MiiOutfitC.png

Comment: It exists in the files, but it's not accessible without modding or hacking methods.